# Why is version info not being displayed

Tags: c++, windows, windres

So I was developing my C++ application when a came across windows resource files (.rc), my application is in portuguese of portugal so I wrote my file like this:

```
MAIN ICON "icon.ico"
MAIN VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,0
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "081604b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "Tenta a tua Sorte!"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Adsglobal"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "Jogo Simples"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © Rodrigo Santos 2020"
            VALUE "OriginalName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0816, 1200
    END
END
```

For some reason that I don't know when I compile it with g++ and windres, I get the icon but the version info isn't displayed.
If you can help me please awnser this

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'isn't not'? Do you mean it *is* displayed and shouldn't be? Because that's what it says. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the wrong ID for the `VERSIONINFO` resource.  Per the [`VERSIONINFO` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/versioninfo-resource), the ID must be `1`, not `MAIN`:

> There are two ways to format a VERSIONINFO statement:
>
> ```
> versionID VERSIONINFO fixed-info  { block-statement . . . }
> ```
>
> - or -
>
> ```
> versionID VERSIONINFO 
> fixed-info
> BEGIN
> block-statement
> ...
> END
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *versionID*
>
> Version-information resource identifier. **This value must be 1.**
>
> ...

So, try this instead:

```
MAIN ICON "icon.ico"
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,0
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "081604b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "Tenta a tua Sorte!"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Adsglobal"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "Jogo Simples"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © Rodrigo Santos 2020"
            VALUE "OriginalName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0816, 1200
    END
END
```

Alternatively, you can use the `VS_VERSION_INFO` macro, which is pre-defined in `<winver.h>`, eg:

```
#include <winver.h>

MAIN ICON "icon.ico"
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,0
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "081604b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "Comments", "Tenta a tua Sorte!"
            VALUE "CompanyName", "Adsglobal"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "Jogo Simples"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright © Rodrigo Santos 2020"
            VALUE "OriginalName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "ProductName", "Tenta a Sorte"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0816, 1200
    END
END
```